# Is there a way to lock volume change using HTML 5 / JS?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, audio, web-audio-api

We are developing an audio app in HTML 5 and I would like to avoid the user to change the volume using the buttons in their iPhones/iPods/iPads/Android Phone. For example, if the try to increase the volume, the app does not change its volume. 
Our app is in iOS today, but we are migrating to HTML 5 and we would like to support that feature in our next app.

Comment: And if a person is hard of hearing, you are preventing them from hearing anything?

Comment: I doubt you could even change the volume of the computer from inside a browser, let alone completely denying the user from changing the volume. Even native applications can't do that. It doesn't even make sense to deny the user from changing the volume. It's *her* computer, your app just runs in it to help her do something or the other. You *shouldn't* have the capability (or the intention) of keeping the user from changing her settings.

Comment: It is for a medical app. The volume should be set by a therapist and sometimes the patient is not allowed to make changes on it. Currently, in iOS we can. What we do is to set the volume at 0.5 everytime the user tries to change it... I have not seen an event fired due to volume change in HTML 5...

Comment: Pretty sure you don't get an event when the user changes the device volume. Just the `volumechange` event when they change the volume of an actual media element (`audio/>`, `<video/>`) .

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to do this.  The pipeline of audio has too many places where gain could be dropped, up to and including an analog resistor in the headphones/speaker themselves.